# How can I tell if C wire is active and connected to Thermostats?

Tags: thermostat, boiler, thermostat-c-wire

We are trying to install a smart thermostat (Ecobee 3) so we are in need of a C wire from our boiler.  We see a green wire in the wall, but it's not connected to our thermostat currently since it doesn't require a C wire.  When we look in the boiler room however, it seems this green wire isn't connected to anything?  The green wire is cut from the main boiler and then there is a cut green wire going up through the ceiling to the thermostat.  It doesn't make sense to us. We're having a very hard time getting an electrician to come do this for us, they keep canceling or are a now show, I don't blame them, I think it's too small of a job for them.  I attached some pictures of the wires, any ideas of what's going on?  Is this fixable for the average DIYer or do we just need to keep waiting for an electrician? Thank you![image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you label where all the cables go in the first photo?  Specifically, there are two cables with white, red, and green wires.  One of them goes to the thermostat (I assume), and one goes somewhere else.  We'll need to know which goes to the thermostat, and where the other goes.

Comment: They are all going up to the thermostat, but the left side of the picture are the wires that appear in the wall behind the thermostat.  The left side of the picture is what comes from the boiler itself...

Comment: You've got two lefts

Comment: OH sorry about that, I meant to say the right side of the picture is where the wires go up into the wall...the left is from the boiler.

Comment: There are two cables on the right (see [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yW0o4.jpg)). Which one goes to the thermostat, and where does the other go?

Comment: Sorry should have been clear, we have two thermostats, they both go to thermostats.

Comment: You're going to need somebody on site to help you, since it's not obvious how things are wired based on your photos.